# How can I ensure that decimal separator will always be "."

Tags: java, bigdecimal, numberformatexception

In Polish regional setting decimal separator is `,`. In english it is `.`. Maybe in other languages there are other separators. (Are there?).

I want to use `BigDecimal`'s String constructor while reading an input file.
In my file I want to use `.` as a decimal separator.

How can I ensure that I don't get `NumberFormatException` if a decimal separator of environment is not `.`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `BigDecimal` constructor - like `Double.parseDouble` etc - *always* uses '.' as a decimal separator. It doesn't use the current culture at all, nor is there any way to specify a number format.

(It would be nice if this were clearly documented, admittedly...)

Comment: Hmmm ... yea, the javadoc for Double.parseDouble refers to Double.valueOf, and that in turn (and in part) refers to the JLS spec of a floating point literal ... without using a hyperlink!